# Largest prime factor in Ruby, without using require 'prime'

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to find the largest prime factor for a number x in Ruby, without using `require 'prime'`.

Here is the code

```
x=13195; n=2; max=n;

for n in (2...x)
  if (x%n==0)
    prime=true
    for y in (1...n)
      if n%y==0
        prime=false
      end
    end
    if prime
      max=n
    end
  end
end

puts max
```

I know the code is loop-extensive. And it not very "Ruby-like'. I just need to understand the logical error in my code.

Comment: Not telling us what's supposed to happen vs. what's actually happening.

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using `require 'prime'` ?

Comment: What do you expect to happen?  What is actually happening?

Comment: @tigeravatar - i can use that. i just want to know why this code isn't working.

Comment: @maerics - I am expecting it to put the largest prime factor of x. Instead its returning a AugmentError

Comment: [SO is not for code dumps](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88842/discourage-code-dumps). Please describe your problem, steps you've taken to try solving it, etc.

Comment: Yes, because your x, n, and max variable initialization isn't right.

Comment: im sorry, clearly im new to SO and programming.

Comment: I corrected the initialization. now the program is crashing

Comment: @aayushgx Describe *how* it is "crashing". You need to provide *details*, not just a bunch of code and "it doesn't work".

Comment: the best thing you can do is delete this question, work more in your code, then create a better question.. also you need to read more about ruby and the ruby standard library, your code doesn't look like ruby at all.

Comment: This will barely work on trivially small numbers, and will struggle with even more modestly sized ones. You're not even caching the results of your computations.

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'prime'

x = 13195

#Solution suggested by steenslag
max = x.prime_divison.last.first

puts max  # => 29
```

Comment: I don't want a solution, I need to know whats wrong with my code

Comment: I have updated my answer to show how to declare multiple variables on the same line, as well as a how to find the largest number that is both a prime and a factor of x.

Comment: thats a great solution. it gives me the solution.. but i still don't know what i did wrong in my original method

Comment: In your original method, you are using `y += 1` and `n += 1` when you are already iterating over a range, there is no need for that and can lead to incorrect results that are very difficult to debug.  You also iterate over the same ranges again and again which is very inefficient and is probably causing the program to lock up.  You need to streamline your code and make it more efficient instead of so loop heavy.

Comment: when i tried running your code, i get an error that says `require': no such file to load -- prime (LoadError)

Comment: also, shouldn't it be x=13195 instead of max? since we are iterating over x and changing max inside the loop?

Comment: `a, b = value1, value2` is interpreted as `a = value1; b = value2`. So in this case, it is interpreted as `x = 13195; max = nil`.  Also, you may have to `require 'rubygems'` prior to requiring prime, especially if you are using an older version of ruby (1.8 for example)

Comment: Requiring prime makes this possible: `p 13195.prime_division.last.first
` To see what the `.last.first` is about, just chop it off.

Comment: Excellent point steenslag, I'll edit my answer to include that :)

Comment: Could you maybe suggest a good compiler for Ruby on Mac? I can't happen to settle on one

Comment: and even after require 'rubygems' , im getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

x is an array

```
x=13195, n=2, max=n # => x == [13195, 2, 2]
```

you need

```
x=13195; n=2; max=n;
```

so, it's obvious that `(2...[13195, 2, 2])` is an invalid `Range`